# Codewars: N-dimensional Von Neumann Neighborhood in a matrix

Tags: python, performance, programming-challenge, recursion, matrix

> **Task:**
>
> For creating [this](https://www.codewars.com/kata/multidimensional-neighbourhood) challenge on Codewars I need a very performant
> function that calculates Von Neumann Neighborhood in a N-dimensional
> array. This function will be called about 2000 times
>
> **The basic recursive approach:**
>
> - calculate the index span influenced by the distance
> - if the index is in the range of the matrix go one step deeper into the next dimension
> - if max dimension is reached - append the value to the global neigh list `isCenter` is just a token that helps to **NOT INCLUDE** the cell
>   itself to the neighbourhood. There is also `remaining_distance` that
>   reduce the span.

You probably do not need to understand the process of this deep math so good. But maybe someone Python experienced can point me to some basic performance upgrade potential the code has.

**Questions:**

- What I am curious about. Is `.append` inefficient? I heard list comprehensions are better than append.
- Would `not (0 <= dimensions_coordinate < len(arr))` changed to `len(arr) <= dimensions_coordinate or dimensions_coordinate < 0)` boost the code?
- Are there performance differences between `==` and `is`?
- Is `dimensions = len(coordinates)... if curr_dim == dimensions:...` slower than `if curr_dim == len(coordinates)`?
- if you understood the math do you see a way to do it iterative? Because I heard recursions are slower in python and theoretical informatics says "Everything recursive can be iterative"

The whole code:

- matrix is a N-dimensional matrix
- coordinates of the cell is a N-length tuple
- distance is the reach of the neighbourhood

---

```
def get_neighbourhood(matrix, coordinates, distance=1):
    dimensions = len(coordinates)
    neigh = []
    app = neigh.append

    def recc_von_neumann(arr, curr_dim=0, remaining_distance=distance, isCenter=True):
        #the breaking statement of the recursion
        if curr_dim == dimensions:
            if not isCenter:
                app(arr)
            return

        dimensions_coordinate = coordinates[curr_dim]
        if not (0 <= dimensions_coordinate < len(arr)):
            return 

        dimesion_span = range(dimensions_coordinate - remaining_distance, 
                              dimensions_coordinate + remaining_distance + 1)
        for c in dimesion_span:
            if 0 <= c < len(arr):
                recc_von_neumann(arr[c], 
                                 curr_dim + 1, 
                                 remaining_distance - abs(dimensions_coordinate - c), 
                                 isCenter and dimensions_coordinate == c)
        return
    
    recc_von_neumann(matrix)
    return neigh
```

Comment: Why remove Moore's neighbourhood?

Comment: @hjpotter92 To make the code simpler. The probably somebody will answer. Because they just differ in "remaining_distance". Everything applied to this code can be applied to Moore too.

Comment: I think these questions would belong better on stack overflow and not here. This is about improving code style, not performance. @S.G you can answer most of your questions yourself by learning how to use the profiler.

Comment: @C.Harley, performance is expressly in scope on code review, per https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @S.G. Could you provide a few example test cases to go with this code? Please also ensure that it runs correctly as written. (e.g. `//` isn't python comment notation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as `lo <= x < hi` expressions go,
my advice is to keep them as-is.
The meaning is clear,
and "optimizing" such an expression
can at best bring only minimal gains.

(With the cPython interpreter,
the only place I tend to deviate from such advice is
turning an expression like `x in [a, b, c]`
into `x in (a, b, c)`, since the bytecode
treats that triple as a constant rather than
as a dynamically allocated data structure.)

---

tiny nit:
[PEP-8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)
asks that you spell it `is_center`. Whatever.

---

In the code

```
        for c in dimesion_span:
            if 0 <= c < len(arr):
                recc_von_neumann(arr[c], 
                                 curr_dim + 1, 
                                 remaining_distance - abs(dimensions_coordinate - c), 
                                 isCenter and dimensions_coordinate == c)
        return
```

please elide the final `return`,
since we're just falling off the end of the function there.

---

LGTM. Ship it!